# How can I stop Android Studion from assuming that Log is in com.esotericsotware.minlog.Log library?

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete

Writing code like `Log.wtf("error group", "error message")` requires including `import android.util.Log`.

In the past import autocompletion for missing `Log` import included both `import android.util.Log` and `com.esotericsotware.minlog.Log` that I do not want to ever use.

Some time ago, something happened and `android.util.Log` got blacklisted, with only `com.esotericsotware.minlog.Log` appearing in the suggestion list.

I want exact opposite, with `com.esotericsotware.minlog.Log` gone and not presented as a suggestion.

I have Android Studio 3.5.2, checking for updates claims that it is the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you can try:

- You can try excluding redundant entries from automatic import so that the list of suggestions contains only relevant items.

  1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog, click **Editor | Auto Import**.
  2. In the **Exclude from Import and Completion** section, click the Add button **+**, and specify a class or a package that you want to exclude.
     You can also select whether you want to exclude items from the current project or from all projects (globally).
     [image]
- Otherwise, you can try disabling auto-imports in Android Studio altogether.

  1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog click **Editor | General | Auto Import**
  2. Unselect the **Add unambiguous imports on the fly** checkbox, and apply the changes.

[image]

You can check out the Android Studio documentation page [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html).

Comment: "Exclude from Import and Completion section" had `android.util.Log`! Thanks for pointing me to it! I am not awarding bounty as SE is blocking it, supposedly it will be available in 5 hours. (feel free to ping me in 5 hours to remind me about it)

Comment: Glad I could help!